# Proc GLM with a list of binary dummy variables

Tags: sas

I am running a regression. My outcome (dependent) is a continuous variable. I have two types of independent variables. One represents day of week. The second type of independent variable is a binary variable (yes/no). I have about 40 of these binary variables. I am only interested in the interaction term between the day of week and all 40 binary variables in my model. I've searched online but could not find a great way to code it:

Sample Code:

```
proc glm
 class dayofweek binvar1-binvar40
 model outcome = dayofweek*binvar1 dayofweek*binvar2...dayofweek*binvar40/solution
run;
```

Is there an easier way to write this?

Comment: FYI: You need to terminate the lines with semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this counts as an easier solution :), but you can construct a macro variable IALL

```
DATA I;
  DO i = 1 TO 40; OUTPUT; END; 
RUN;
PROC SQL NOPRINT;
   SELECT VAR into: IALL SEPARATED BY " " FROM (SELECT CATS("dayofweek*binvar",PUT(I,2.0)) AS VAR FROM I);
QUIT;
```

and use it in PROC GLM

```
proc glm
class dayofweek binvar1-binvar40
model outcome = &IALL. /solution
run;
```